# Missed Prayers and Fast due to not knowing about rules

Tags: salat, women, sawm, menses, mistake

As-salaam 'Alaykum. I got my period in almost two years ago in 2019. I was 11 when I got my period. I thought that praying and fasting were based on age. This year was the first year I fasted for all of Ramadan and have been praying consistently. I was not aware that once a girl sees her period that fasting and praying become mandatory. Do I have to make up the prayer and fasts that I missed even though I was didn't know I was supposed to?

Answer (score -1):

You do not have to perform the fasts that you did not do because you did not know the Shari'a ruling. But you should recite the prayers of that period with the intention of qada.